# Creating clusters based on nearest distance attribute in ArcMap using ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.3, distance, clustering

I am attempting to create a tool via modelbuilder that creates clustering for a polygon feature class based on the distance field attribute (between one polygon to another) that I have created using the "near table" tool. There are some requirements to the clustering process:

Firstly, I would like the cluster to be grouped in an "ascending" method, where the "first" polygons to be grouped together are those with the shortest distance. (i.e. Polygon A and Polygon B with distance of 200m (shortest distance) are grouped together first)

Secondly, I would also like the grouping to be such that once a set of polygons are grouped together in a cluster, they are excluded from the clustering process, which continues on until all polygons are grouped in their own respective clusters based on the distance field attribute.

I would like to know if there is are methods within Arcmap that ultimately allows me to create the clusters through the use of a tool created using modelbuilder, as the existing geoprocessing tools for creating *clusters* do not have the options that allows me to fulfill the 2 requirements above. 
My arcgis desktop is advanced license.